# Equivalent of a partial sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series

I try to find an equivalent of $S_n=\sum \limits_{k=3}^{n}\frac{1}{k.\log(k).\log(\log(k))}$.

I know that, according to the condensation test with $p=2$, this positive series has the same behavior as $\sum \limits_{n\ge 2}\frac{1}{n.\log(2).\log(n.\log(2))}$ which is divergent by Bertrand's criterion.

Then I tried to find an equivalent of $S_n '=\sum \limits_{k = 2}^n\frac{1}{k.\log(2).\log(k.\log(2))}$ using the integral's test and found that $S_n ' \sim \log(\log(\log(2^n)))$. But apparently $S_n\sim\log(\log(\log(n))).$

I know that $\frac{1}{n.\log(2).\log(n.\log(2))}\not \sim \frac{1}{n.\log(n).\log(\log(n))}$ but it does not imply that $S_n ' \not \sim S_n$. So why can't we find the same result ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_3^{n+1}\frac1{x\log x\log\log x}\,dx\le S_n\le\frac1{3\log 3\log \log 3}+ \int_3^n\frac1{x\log x\log\log x}\,dx$$
Therefore,
$$
S_n\sim \int_3^n \frac1{x\log x\log\log x}\,dx
$$

---

If you want to use the Cauchy condensation trick to find an equivalent for the *partial* sums, you have to be careful. The logic behind the condensation test is
$$
a_1+(a_2+a_3)+(a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7)+\dots\le a_1+2a_2+4a_4+\dots,\\
\implies \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k}
$$
So the first three terms of the condensed series account for the first seven terms of the original. In general, the first $k$ terms of the condensed series account for the first $2^k-1$ terms of the original. You can also show on the other end that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k}\le 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k
$$

Now, letting $a_k=1/(k\log k\log \log k)$, so that
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=3}^n a_{k}
$$
$$
S_m'=\sum_{k=3}^m a_{k}
$$
then the same trick use in proving the Cauchy condensation test for the whole series implies the following inequalities for the partial sums:
$$
S_{2^n+1}\le S'_{n+2}\le 2S_{2^n+1}
$$
Note the indice mismatch; the condensed partial sums coerrespond to many terms in the original.
This is now consistent with the results
$$
S_n\sim \log \log \log n\\
S_n'\sim \log \log \log 2^n
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, I know that the equivalent is given with the integral's test and then you can compute the integral. But it does not answer at my thoughts

Comment: @Maman Cauchy's condensation test only works for infinite sums, as far as I know. How did you justify applying it to the finite sum $S_n$?

Comment: I just use the integral's test with a divergent series which give you an equivalent of the partial sum (last line you wrote). Indeed the condensation's test claims that the initial series has the same behavior as the series of the form $2^nu_{2^n}$. So if it is divergent you can apply the integral's test to find an equivalent of $S_n '$. And for the two series we find two different equivalents...

Comment: The condensation test only says that $u_n$ and $2^nu_{2^n}$ either both converge or both diverge. It does not guarantee that if they diverge, they diverge at the same rate.

Comment: @Maman See edits for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations !